# Rendering 3D file with Three js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, three.js

Its my first time using three.js and I'm trying to display a simple 3d model using three js, vue and laravel. The 3D file is in */public/files/Tree1.3ds*. How do I render the file in the vue component with three js. I've copied the code from the three js official docs and it works fine but if I change directly the file path to the scene.add() it doesn't work. Thanks.

**Vue**

```
<script>
import * as THREE from 'three';
let camera, scene, renderer;
let geometry, material, mesh;
export default {
    methods:{
        init() {
        
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
            camera.position.z = 1;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
        
            geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
            material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            //scene.add( mesh );
            scene.add('http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/Tree1.3ds')   
     
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
        },
        animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );
            mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init()
        this.animate()
    }
   }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Changed the loader type but all i get is an empty scene.

```
import { TDSLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/TDSLoader.js';

var loader = new TDSLoader( );
loader.load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/Tree1.3ds', function(obj) {
    scene.add( obj );
});
```

Comment: You need to use a loader and add the object to the scene in its callback: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_3ds.html (check the source code)

Comment: check my update question. thanks @ChrisG

Comment: You need the TDSLoader for 3ds files, not a texture loader.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the correct type of loader. 3ds is a specific file type that must be loaded with the appropriate loader file. Right now you use a TextureLoader that is meant for textures.

There is an example for 3ds files on the examples page
[Code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_3ds.html) line 47 - 49

Comment: im getting black screen